# "For background on .." vs. "for a backgroun on .."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

This is somewhat tricky articles case:

> For a background on X, see ..

vs.

> For background on X, see ..

By background, I mean background about a specific topic to build knowledge on it.

Comment: Both are possible. You would use the indefinite article if you are talking about one of many *countable* backgrounds, but omit the article if you are talking about *background* in a generic, mass noun sense. (You can also use the definite article if it's a countable and you're specifying a specifically identified background among many.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more complete to say:

> For a background on X, see ...

The form without the indefinite article somehow sounds incomplete.

If you use the indefinite article, it is not self-understood that the background is just a slice of information. It can be many slices of information from many areas, but all these slices together do not provide 100% of the background.

If you use the definite article:

> For **the** background on X, see ...

than the referenced "location" ("see ...") is supposed to provide all the details.